# Updating Data, Getting User ID To Be Dynamic?

Tags: codeigniter, function

I wrote syntax allowing my users to update their user information but I’m having a problem. For testing purposes I hard-coded the user_id of 24 into my syntax but I want that user_id to be dynamic. My question is, how would I get my users ID? The below syntax works (I haven’t added form validation but I soon will) when it comes to updating user data I have to dynamically get their ID. Looking at the below snytax how would I go about doing that? Thanks everyone.

My Controller

```
public function update_records(){

  $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

  $form_data = array(
  'business' => $this->input->post('business'),
  'user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id'),
  'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
  'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
  'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
  'zip' => $this->input->post('zip'),
  'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
  'website' => $this->input->post('website'),
  'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
  'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
  'time' => $now
  );

  $this->load->model('Change_data');
  $this->Change_data->update_function_three($form_data);
```

My Model

```
function update_function_three($formdata){
// How would I make '24' dynamic?  
$this->db->where('user_id', '24');
$this->db->update('business',$formdata);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you would just do

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $formdata['user_id']);
```

Or when the user logs in you could save their user_id to a session with

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $userId);
```

and then do

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
```

Comment: Hi Pattle, thanks for your help. I'm playing around with this syntax and my goal isn't to pass the user IDs but to store it in a session. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $formdata['user_id']);
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help. It works but now I'm working on not passing the users ID in a form. From what I understand, that's not smart. Thanks for your help